# Refresh data with API every X minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails 4.1.4

I made an interface to a Twitch gem, to fetch information of the current stream, mainly whether it is online or not, but also stuff like the current title and game being played.

Since the website has a lot of traffic, I can't make a request every time a user walks in, so instead I need to cache this information.

Cached information is stored as a class variable @@stream_data inside class: Twitcher.

I've made a rake task to update this using cronjobs, calling Twitcher.refresh_stream, but naturally that is not running within my active process (to which every visitor is connecting to) but instead a separate process. So the @@stream_data on the actual app is always empty.

Is there a way to run code, within my currently running rails app, every X minutes? Or a better approach, for that matter.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why don't you store the result of the scrape in your app's database?

Comment: Hm I don't know about using the database to store that... Like a whole Model just for one entry. Is that an okay practice?

Comment: It's not odd if you create a new row every time you pull the data from the API. Then you have historical data. Or if in the future you want to add more streams to your "watch list". Then you could add each of these to the database table. It may not be the most efficient right now, but it is probably the most scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good call for caching

```
Rails.cache.fetch("stream_data", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
  fetch_new_data
end
```

If the data is in the cache and is not old then it will be returned without executing the block, if not the block is used to populate the cache.

The default cache store just keeps things in memory so doesn't fix your problem: you'll need to pick a cache store that is shared across your processes. Both redis and memcached (via the dalli gem) are popular choices.

Comment: This is actually interesting, and I'll just mark it as solution because I think others with the same issue will find it useful. Although what I eventually did, was using databases to store data. Then with Whenever (which I am already using for other stuff), I set up a Rake Task to "refresh twitch data", storing new data. Similar to what someone suggested, but this implementation allows "caching" multiple kind of API data.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) (basically a ruby interface to cron) to invoke something on a regular schedule.

Comment: I did that, but creates a new process/instance, and doesn't affect my runtime variables :/

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar problem with using google analytics. Google analytics requires that you have an API key for each request. However the api key would expire every hour. If you requested a new api key for every google analytics request, it'd be very slow per request.

So what I did was make another class variable `@@expires_at`. Now in every method that made a request to google analytics, I would check `@@expires_at.past?`. If it was true, then I would refresh the api key and set `@@expires_at = 45.minutes.from_now`.

You can do something like this.

```
def method_that_needs_stream_data
  renew_data if @@expires_at.past?
  # use @@stream_data
end

def renew_data
  # renew @@stream_data here
  @@expires_at = 5.minutes.from_now
end
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Yea I almost do that, but didn't like the idea of checking every time, and then slowing the user down on the request because I needed to go fetch data :P But close of doing this.